# Java Program is generating empty zip file

Tags: java

I have a program. That writes a file in a directory and then use that written file to add it into the Zip file.

Now, the files are generating successfully. But Zip file is generating empty.
I have also checked the zip entry that its a file name because it does not put entry in zip with absolute file paths..

But the issue persist. Any help will be appreciated :)

**Zip Generation Method**

```
// Function to write files in ZIP archive..
public void writeToZip( String ibftDirectory, ZipOutputStream zipOS ) throws Exception {

        LOGGER.println( "Writing file = " + ibftDirectory + " to zip file" );

        // Initialize File..
        File file = new File( ibftDirectory );  

        // Open stream of file..
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream( file );

        // Get entry name..
        String entryName = getFileName( ibftDirectory );

        // Create zip entry..
        ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry( entryName );

        // Add zip entry...
        zipOS.putNextEntry( zipEntry );

        // Create byte array..
        byte[] bytes = new byte[ 1024 ];

        // Length of stream holder..
        int length;

        // Write to zip..
        while ( ( length = fis.read( bytes ) ) >= 0 ) {

            zipOS.write( bytes, 0, length );

        }

        LOGGER.println( "File = " + ibftDirectory + " added to zip successfully!" );

        // Close streams to avoid memory leaks..
        zipOS.closeEntry();

     fis.close();   

}
```

**ZIP Calling**

```
public class UploadFileWithSecurity extends IbftUtil implements IConstants {

    private FileOutputStream fileOS = null;
    private ZipOutputStream zipOS = null;  

public void uploadFiles ( String filename, String filePaymentRecord, String ibftDirectoryPath ) throws Exception {

        // To overcome the IBM JCE Limitation..
        Security.addProvider( new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider() );

        setKeys();

        String signatureFileName = "sign_" + filename.replace(".csv", ".sig");
        String keyFileName = "key_" + filename.replace(".csv", ".key");

        try {

            fileOS = new FileOutputStream( ibftDirectoryPath + filename.replace( ".csv" , ".zip") );
            zipOS = new ZipOutputStream( fileOS );      

        }
        catch ( Exception e ) {
            LOGGER.println( "Exception in outputstream of Zip file.. " + e );
        }
        String sign = sign( filehash , privateKeySender );

        writeFile( sign, signatureFileName, ibftDirectoryPath );

        try {

            writeToZip( ibftDirectoryPath + signatureFileName, zipOS );

        }
        catch ( Exception e ) {

            LOGGER.println( "Exception in writing of Zip file.. " + e );

        }
String encryptedKey = RSAEncrypt( AESParams.getKey().getEncoded(), "Key" );     

        LOGGER.println( LOG + " symmetric key encrypted.. " );

        // Write the encrypted symmetric key in a file..
        writeFile( encryptedKey, keyFileName, ibftDirectoryPath );

        try {

            writeToZip( ibftDirectoryPath + keyFileName, zipOS );

            zipOS.close();
            fileOS.close();

        }
        catch ( Exception e ) {

            LOGGER.println( "Exception in writing of Zip file.. " + e );

        }
    }
}
```

**Get Filename Function**

```
// Get file name... 
public String getFileName ( String path ) {

    String filename = path.substring( path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1 );      

    LOGGER.println( "Filename extracted = " + filename );

    return filename;
 }
```

Comment: Using the code snippets you posted I can produce non-empty zip files. Are you sure that no exceptions are logged?

Comment: Yes there is no exception. However, please note that the complete jar file is deployed on AIX server and the paths are provided according to that.

Comment: However, same code on windows is producing non empty zips

Comment: It's worth to count and log the length of the input file after you complete writing to the zip.

Comment: You mean I shall print the length before ```zOS.write``` ?

Comment: I have checked the lengths, 3 files have lengths = 344, 320 and 344 respectively